# I need to set a default option for a javascript array (drop down field)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have inherited this code that populates the countries in my online checkout. The first value that shows up is Australia but I need it to be set to USA.

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
    $(function(){
        $('#FormField_11>option, #FormField_21>option').each(function () {
            // PUT THE COUNTRIES YOU WANT TO KEEP IN THE LIST HERE
            var countries = [ 'United States', 'Canada', 'Belgium', 'Australia', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Germany', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands Antilles', 'New Zealand', 'Norway', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom', 'Austria'  ];

            var country = $(this).text();
            if (countries.indexOf(country) == -1) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>​
```

Can anyone help me define United States as the default?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just want `United States` selected by default, or if you want it moved to the top of the `select`?

Comment: I want the United States selected by default

Answer (score 1):

After you remove all the unwanted countries, set the values of the dropdowns to the desired default:

```
$(function(){
    $('#FormField_11>option, #FormField_21>option').each(function () {
        // PUT THE COUNTRIES YOU WANT TO KEEP IN THE LIST HERE
        var countries = [ 'United States', 'Canada', 'Belgium', 'Australia', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Germany', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands Antilles', 'New Zealand', 'Norway', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom', 'Austria'  ];

        var country = $(this).text();
        if (countries.indexOf(country) == -1) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    $("#FormField_11, #FormField_21").value("United States");
});
```

Comment: That didn't work - - -  BUT - I changed it to  $("#FormField_11, #FormField_21").value("United States"); because I thought you had a typo in it.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.